# Byte array in C with data from files with zeros inside

Tags: c, byte

I need to edit each `byte` in an application, and I need to store it somewhere. First I used `char*` or `unsigned char*`, but when I read a more complex files which contains zero's the whole thing doesn't work any more (zero equals `'\0'` a.k.a end of string). What should I use instead?

Comment: Use `unsigned char*`. Just don't use string handling functions if what you have aren't strings.

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned char *` is the proper data type, you simply need to store the number of bytes you have in a separate variable.

Always remember that you are dealing with bytes, not strings/characters - so you cannot use any string functions as they expect terminated strings.

- If you want the length, use your variable that contains it
- If you want to compare bytes, use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to load a file which has zeros inside (binary file) just use stat() on the file to get the size of the file and write it into the array with a loop till the indexer has the same value with the size of the file minus 1 or use this method:

```
struct stat fistat;
//get the size of the file
if(stat("filename",&fistat)<0) {
    printf("file not found\n");
    return 1;
}
// open the file
FILE* file = fopen("filename","r");
if (!file){
    printf("can't open file\n");
    return 1;
}
unsigned char buff[fistat.st_size];
// write the file to buffer
fread(buff,fistat.st_size,1,file);
fclose(file);
```

this way you have your file in the `buff` which has the size `fistat.st_size`.